# How to handle multiple http requests using single instance of HttpClient?

Tags: c#, json, .net, linq, dotnet-httpclient

after doing some research I got to know that it's best to instantiate HttpClient once and then reuse it's instance everwhere else.

My GetAsync requests are working absolutely fine. However, with PostAsync I'm getting error.

Please find my code below :

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;  
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; 
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Mime;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        public static async Task Main(string[] args) 
        {
            string Event_MSG ="[{\"ID\":354,\"EventTimeStamp\":\"2022-05-
            17T05:35:25\",\"Title\":\"Failedtoretrieveequipmentlogs\",\"ControllerId\":24,
            \"Details\":\"UnabletoretrievelogsfromdeviceP25-SC- 
            023322.Cyclepoweratfieldunit.Iftheproblemreturns,contactyourHunterrepresentative.\",
            \"ControllerName\":\"P25-SC-0233\"},{\"ID\":353,\"EventTimeStamp\":\"2022-05- 
            17T05:34:20\",\"Title\":\"Failedtoretrieveequipmentlogs\",\"ControllerId\":17,
            \"Details\":\"UnabletoretrievelogsfromdeviceP25-SC- 
            022615.Cyclepoweratfieldunit.Iftheproblemreturns,contactyourHunterrepresentative.\",
            \"ControllerName\":\"P25-SC-0226\"},{\"ID\":352,\"EventTimeStamp\":\"2022-05- 
            17T05:33:50\",\"Title\":\"Failedtoretrieveequipmentlogs\",\"ControllerId\":16,
            \"Details\":\"UnabletoretrievelogsfromdeviceP25-SC- 
            022514.Cyclepoweratfieldunit.Iftheproblemreturns,contactyourHunterrepresentative.\",
            \"ControllerName\":\"P25-SC-0225\"},{\"ID\":351,\"EventTimeStamp\":\"2022-05- 
            17T05:33:20\",\"Title\":\"Failedtoretrieveequipmentlogs\",\"ControllerId\":15,
            \"Details\":\"UnabletoretrievelogsfromdeviceP25-SC- 
            022413.Cyclepoweratfieldunit.Iftheproblemreturns,contactyourHunterrepresentative.\",
            \"ControllerName\":\"P25-SC-0224\"},{\"ID\":350,\"EventTimeStamp\":\"2022-05- 
            17T05:32:50\",\"Title\":\"Failedtoretrieveequipmentlogs\",\"ControllerId\":14,
            \"Details\":\"UnabletoretrievelogsfromdeviceP25-SC- 
            022312.Cyclepoweratfieldunit.Iftheproblemreturns,contactyourHunterrepresentative.\",
            \"ControllerName\":\"P25-SC-0223\"}]";

            Console.WriteLine("Starting connections");

            List<KeyValue> keyvalue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValue>>(Event_MSG);
            JArray EventMSG = JArray.Parse(Event_MSG);
            int i = 0;
            foreach(var item in EventMSG)
            {
                var inc_val = i++;

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
                AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic","auth_val");

                HttpResponseMessage get_response = await 
                client.GetAsync("https://myurl.com/"+keyvalue[inc_val]);
                var get_responseString = await get_response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                JObject obj = JObject.Parse(get_responseString);
                string DeviceID = (string) obj["managedObject"]["id"];

                string isoTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");

                string c8y_payloadString =    $"{{\"time\": \"{isoTime}\",\"source\": {{\"id\": \" 
                {DeviceID}\" }},\"type\": \"c8y_Golf_Controller\",\"text\": \"PilotCC Event\"}}";
                JObject c8y_payloadObject = JObject.Parse(c8y_payloadString);
                var c8y_finalPayload = new JObject();
                c8y_finalPayload.Merge(item);
                c8y_finalPayload.Merge(c8y_payloadObject);
                string c8y_finalPayloadString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c8y_finalPayload);

                Console.WriteLine(get_responseString);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", 
                "application/vnd.com.nsn.cumulocity.event+json");
                var stringContent = new StringContent(c8y_finalPayloadString, Encoding.UTF8, 
                MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);
                stringContent.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "";
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://myurl.com", 
                stringContent);
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                Console.WriteLine(responseString);


            }
            Console.WriteLine("Connections done");

        }
    }
    public class KeyValue
    {
        [JsonProperty("ControllerName")]
        public string ControllerName { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
            {
                return String.Format(ControllerName);
            }
    }
}
```

Now If I remove the following lines from the code, it works completely fine and returns correct json response for all 5 get requests :

**POST REQUEST CODE**

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", 
"application/vnd.com.nsn.cumulocity.event+json");

var stringContent = new StringContent(c8y_finalPayloadString, Encoding.UTF8, 
MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);

stringContent.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "";

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://myurl.com", stringContent);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Console.WriteLine(responseString);
```

But when I'm using this it throws an error : -

```
Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json)
   at ConsoleApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 31
   at ConsoleApplication.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Only the first iteration runs successfully making both GetAsync and PostAsync calls, after that I get the above error.
Line which is throwing error is : `JObject obj = JObject.Parse(get_responseString);` and it is because in second iteration the get request is not returning any response(happening only when the lines in **POST REQUEST CODE** are included)

Sample Get Request response : -

```json
{"managedObject":{"self":"https://url.co/inventory/managedObjects/43432113",
"id":"43432113"},"externalId":"P25-SC-0233","self":"https://url.co/identity/externalIds/c8y_Serial/P25-SC-0233",
"type":"c8y_Serial"}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You usually shouldn't use `DefaultRequestHeaders` unless you configure them once at the beginning of the app. Instead, add the headers to each request.

Comment: @StephenCleary how to add headers to each request?

Comment: Create an `HttoRequestMessage` and set the headers on that before sending. Then when you get the `HttpResponseMessage` back, call `EnsureSuccessStatusCode`.